# get the week end date given the year and the week number in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and it has 2 columns 'Year' and 'week number'. I need to find the week end date and add it in the dataframe.

I am new to python and need your support here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fromisocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar) to get based on year and week number and given day in week (6 for Saturday) it's date:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2010, 2009],
'week number':[23, 5]})

from datetime import date

df['end_week'] = df.apply(lambda x : date.fromisocalendar(x['year'], x['week number'], 6).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), axis=1)

print(df)
```

For Python versions previous to and including 3.6:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2010, 2009],
'week number':[23, 5]})

from datetime import datetime

def date_from_isoweek(year, week, day):
    return datetime.strptime(f"{year:04d} {week:02d} {day:d}", "%G %V %u").date()

df['end_week'] = df.apply(lambda x : date_from_isoweek(x['year'], x['week number'], 6).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   year  week number    end_week
0  2010           23  12/06/2010
1  2009            5  31/01/2009
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks you for the response, but i am getting error "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'fromisocalendar'. Why so?

Comment: my code:
from datetime import date

final_DF['end_week'] = final_DF.apply(lambda x : date.fromisocalendar(x['week_ending_year'], x['week_no'], 6).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), axis=1)

print(final_DF)

Comment: @WasimAkramKhan make sure to use Python 3.8

Comment: checked again the python version in my system is 3.8.5.
is this a problem?

Comment: That's peculiar because [it should work with Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar). 
Do you have multiple Python installations?

Comment: @WasimAkramKhan added another version that is compatible with Python versions before and including 3.6, just in case

Comment: Hello Aviv,

There was an older version of Anaconda, which i updated and now your initial code is working fine.. You are a life saver for me.. Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong. It should include an example of input and the output
also, I think you can do that with **datetime** standard library